# Audio processing library for android

Tags: android, audio-processing, pitch-detection

Does anyone know a library for audio processing on android? I need to extract pitch and speech power (intensity).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [this](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP) library out. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any way to extract pitch-time feature from that?

Comment: Yes. Open the library and check out TarsosDSP Example Applications

 Portion. You'll get pitch detector.

Comment: Do mark my answer as correct if I was able to solve your problem.

Comment: To get better intuition about *Audio Processing*, you can visit this reference:
[Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android-Audio-Processing-Using-WebRTC)